# Composer wont update to lastest package

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, uploader

I'm using Cakephp and Miles's uploader plugin. I've got the composer plugin installed, and I'm using the latest copy of wamp. Fileinfo extension is enabled in php. when I try to update using composer it doesn't - it just uses a previous version. If I change the json file to force an update to the latest version I get and error message telling me the ext-fileinfo is not present - but it is.............

I need to get the lastest version as I have an error which shows up on my webserver which is running php 5.3 (wamp is using 5.4)

Additional info:-

The main composer.json is :-

```
{"config":{"vendor-dir":"Vendor"},
    "require": {
        "mjohnson/uploader": "4.3.*",
        "mjohnson/utility": "1.5.*",
        "mjohnson/decoda": "*",
        "titon/utility": "*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

I'm expecting mjohnson/uploader to update (

a sub set composer.JSON is held in the uploader package :-

```
{
    "name": "mjohnson/uploader",
    "type": "cakephp-plugin",
    "description": "File uploader and validation plugin for CakePHP.",
    "keywords": ["cakephp", "uploader", "plugin", "file", "validation", "attachment"],
    "homepage": "http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Miles Johnson",
            "homepage": "http://milesj.me"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "composer/installers": "*",`enter code here`
        "mjohnson/transit": ">=1.4"
    },
    "support": {
        "source": "https://github.com/milesj/Uploader"
    }
}
```

and I would also have expected mjohnson/transit to have updated

Comment: We'd really need more info, first and foremost your `composer.json` file. You should also state which component of the libraries you expect to get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with ext-fileinfo and ext-curl on Windows 7. My problem was the path variable causing the wrong php.exe to be executed by composer. If php -m from the command line shows ext-fileinfo is not present that could be your problem too.